# Código mais eficiente para fazer um template em iTextSharp em ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itextsharp

Só fiz um projecto para gerar PDF's usando a biblioteca iTextSharp em ASP.NET MVC (C#), no entanto, gostaria de saber qual o código mais eficiente e fácil de utilizar para ter um template que gere PDF usando iTextSharp em ASP.NET MVC (C#), que código a incluir no Controller/Model/View?Precisava de poder introduzir nesse PDF cabeçalho e rodapé sempre iguais(logotipos/nome/morada/data) e no corpo do PDF imagens e/ou texto!
Que código colocar no Controller/Model/View?

Comment: O que seria na sua opinião mais fácil de utilizar?

Comment: Aquela que teria menos linhas de código e menor uso da memória!

Answer (score -2):

O código mais eficiente inclui usar [uma biblioteca que é da minha autoria](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorPDF2/). Funciona com todas as versões do iTextSharp, incluindo a versão 4, que está embutida no projeto. A ideia geral é transformar uma *View* Razor em PDF.

[Aqui tem exemplos de uso](https://github.com/DesignLiquido/RazorPDF2/tree/master/RazorPDFExample).

Caso queira usar apenas o iTextSharp da versão 5 em diante, pode usar diretamente a [MVcRazorToPdf](https://github.com/andyhutch77/MvcRazorToPdf).